# How to populate fields after mapReduce with Mongoose.js?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I want to populate fields after mapReduce.

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('createdCollectionNameForResults', function(err, collection) { 
    collection.find({}).populate('ref_field').toArray(function(err, items) { 
           res.send(200, items)
    });
});
```

But here, it gives error:

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'populate'**

Because collection.find({}) returns mongodb cursor. How can I populate ref_field?

Comment: You're calling `find` on the native driver collection.  You need to be calling `find` on a Mongoose model for `populate` to work.

Comment: Yes but how I should do that?

Comment: Create a schema and model for your collection that your `mapReduce` creates and then query it like any other mongoose model.  See [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have a Schema registered in mongoose named 'createdCollectionNameForResults'

```
var Model = mongoose.model('createdCollectionNameForResults');
Model.find({}).populate('ref_field').exec(function(err, results){
   console.log(err, results); 
});
```